# Replace HTML5 audio with Web Audio API

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

HTML5 audio on mobile devices has many limitations and actually I would call them bugs.

My app implementing something like audio player.

Actually all it works fine for desktop but in mobile version I encounter many bugs and have to do many workarounds different for different browsers and os to get it work, and still it sucks.

I haven't dived into web audio api, but it seems to be designed for slightly different tasks.

So my question is, is it make sense (and is it possible?) to replace HTML5 audio with Web Audio API, if I need just to load files and play them (partly, sprites) just to avoid limitations and bugs of HTML5 audio?

Comment: They suffer from the exact same implementation bugs and limitations.  Otherwise, you're going to have to be much more specific.  Sure, you can use one of the JavaScript-implemented codecs instead, but I'm not sure that's what you're getting at.

Comment: I want just be able to load several audio files and play them (one at a time). Event for this simple task mobile HTML5 audio sucks.

Comment: That is the current state of things.

Comment: Checkout the library https://github.com/vjai/musquito, it helps to play sounds with html5 audio or web audio easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're probably going to find at least as many bugs or edge cases with Web Audio on mobile as you're seeing using the `<audio>` element. Plus, support for Web Audio on mobile platforms isn't great. If it were me, I'd be inclined to stick with `<audio>` unless you have a specific use-case that can only be addressed by the Web Audio API.

Comment: It's also important to remember that the Web Audio API doesn't get around the most common issue people have with audio on mobile browsers: trying to play the audio without direct physical interaction from the user.

Comment: I disagree, in general I've found the <audio> element implementation almost unusable on mobile devices compared to the mostly smooth experience with Web Audio.  The only use-case that I find audio element may be better is in playing a single larger file.

Comment: The impression I got from the question, and especially the comment "I want just be able to load several audio files and play them (one at a time)" was that that's exactly what the OP wants to do.

Comment: for now I choose to stick with <audio> tag

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'll disagree - if your goal is to play short snippets of sounds, particularly simultaneously - e.g., providing sound for a platform jumper game - Web Audio is going to be a lot easier to use, including on mobile.   has issues managing multiple files/instances.  On the other hand, if the problems you're running in to are due to decoding issues, or you're using mostly long files, it's not going to help, as Kevin and Brad said.

Comment: Totally agreed. For those kinds of tasks, Web Audio is really the only way to go. I was just basing my answer off the comment above: "I want just be able to load several audio files and play them (one at a time)."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) which I develop, it takes a lot of the pain out of supporting audio on multiple devices.  Basically it lets you write a single code base that works everywhere and already deals with edge cases where it can.

HTML Audio element implementation on mobile devices is really terrible, so if not SoundJS I would at least recommend switching to Web Audio which works well on iOS and Android Chrome but is not supported in Android Native browser.

idbehold's comment is accurate, the most common problem with mobile devices is having to play audio inside of a user initiated event (touch).  I've developed a solution to this problem, shared in the [Mobile Safe Approach tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/).

Hope that helps.